# I just got a large error message ive never seen before, what does it mean?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\happy\Documents\Python\Python Hangman Files\Python Hangman EXE.py", line 253, in <module>
    wordchoice = randint(0, len(words)-1)
  File "C:\Users\happy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 220, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\happy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 198, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

I got this error, and I don't know what its referring to, or what is wrong with the code, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you need to show code

Comment: It would help if you showed the code particularly around line 198. That's the line it's referring to. It says you have an empty range. The error message gives useful information about where to look and the context of the call sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `len(words)` is 0, so `len(words) - 1` is -1, so `random` cannot generate a number in the range. I can't be sure how to fix this, because I don't have your code.

Comment: thanks, I will look for this in my code, and see if I can solve it

Comment: this fixed it, thanks, there was an error earlier in the program where items weren't being added to the list: words

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used the function`randint()` which use `randrange()` without giving a range of the number - and that not valid.
you should use it like this:

random.randrange **([start], stop[, step])**

for example:

```
random.randrange(1,1000)
```

will give you a number between 1 to 1000.

```
random.randrange(1,1000,2)
```

will do the same but with jumps of 2 (I.e.1,3,5...)

Comment: If you look at the traceback you see `wordchoice = randint(0, len(words) - 1)`

Comment: @pycoder I can see where I might have gone wrong there, ill have a look and see if I can fix it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you already have your problem reason. It is indeed the fact that `words` is empty, and the `randrange()` method [don't handle this kind of input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange).

You can always check if your variable (in this case `words`) is empty, simply using:

```
if len(words) > 0:
    wordchoice = randint(0, len(words)-1)
```

Comment: yep, that was the problem, there was an error my code where items weren't being added to 'words', thanks